# Apple rejected 4 apps at a same time with the same reason

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have send 4 apps for review to the app store. Apple takes build of apps for review on May 21, 2017 at 5:29 AM and rejected all apps on same time on May 21, 2017 at 5:46 AM. Apple has given below reason.

I am not able to understand the reason. Please help me.

> **0. 10.0 Before You Submit: Program License Agreement**
>
> We have determined that your Apple Developer Program membership, or
>   another membership associated with your developer account, has been
>   used for dishonest or fraudulent activity. This is prohibited by
>   Section 3.2(f) of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement:
>
> "You will not, directly or indirectly, commit any act intended to
>   interfere with the Apple Software or Services, the intent of this
>   Agreement, or Apple’s business practices including, but not limited
>   to, taking actions that may hinder the performance or intended use of
>   the App Store, B2B Program, or the Program.”
>
> As a result of this activity, you are no longer able to submit
>   updates.
>
> Continuing to engage in dishonest or fraudulent acts may result in the
>   removal of your apps from the App Store and termination of your Apple
>   Developer Program membership and all associated memberships.
>
> This letter is not intended to be a complete statement of the facts
>   regarding this matter, and nothing in this letter should be construed
>   as a waiver of any rights or remedies Apple may have, all of which are
>   hereby reserved
>
> Best regards, App Store Review

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about AppStore policies and not about programming.

Comment: @ShamasS than in which stack overflow community I have to post this question?

Comment: Did you try in Itunes Connect to know more about your issue by responding to the reject? They may help you to clarify it.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya I'm really sorry but I'm not sure about which SE community would this belong to. From what I can see is that they think your account is involved in some sort of fraudulent behaviour. I guess your safest bet would be contact them back and ask for more clarification.

Comment: @ShamasS ok let me send a reply.

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Comment: @LionHeart not yet.

Comment: This means that account is terminated.

Comment: I had same issue, They terminated for unknown reason. They don't gave any reason. Just sent constant message.

Comment: @RajamohanS Forgot about that account, that will not active.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya, Yeah they are terminated my account. They don't know exact reason. Impressed with Apple. lol